# Search in Toolbar is force closing my app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-search

I have my main actionbaractivity MainDrawer2:

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final String EXTRA_NAV_ITEM    = "extraNavItem";
    private static final String STATE_CURRENT_NAV = "stateCurrentNav";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;


    private NavDrawerListAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private MainNavItem mCurrentNavItem;


    public static Intent createLaunchFragmentIntent(Context context, MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        return new Intent(context, MainDrawer2.class)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM, navItem.ordinal());
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);



        //Crashlytics.start(this);



        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //enableHomeButtonIfRequired();

        mDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                displayNavFragment((MainNavItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM)){
            MainNavItem navItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM,
                    MainNavItem.STATISTICS.ordinal())];
            displayNavFragment(navItem);
        }
        else if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentNavItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV)];
            setCurrentNavItem(mCurrentNavItem);
        }
        else{
            displayNavFragment(MainNavItem.STATISTICS);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void enableHomeButtonIfRequired()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        //getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title)
    {
        mTitle = title;
        //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        if (mCurrentNavItem == null){


        }
        else{
            outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV, mCurrentNavItem.ordinal());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    */



    private void displayNavFragment(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        //if(navItem == mCurrentNavItem){
        //  return;
        //}
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                navItem.getFragClass().getName());
        if(fragment != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                    .commit();
            //setCurrentNavItem(navItem);
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentNavItem(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        int position = navItem.ordinal();
        // If navItem is in DrawerAdapter
        if(position >= 0 && position < mDrawerAdapter.getCount()){
            //mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        else{
            // navItem not in DrawerAdapter, de-select current item
            if(mCurrentNavItem != null){
                //mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mCurrentNavItem.ordinal(), false);
            }
        }

        //test to keep item not selected
        int toClear=mDrawerList.getCheckedItemPosition();

        if (toClear >= 0) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(toClear, false);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        //setTitle(navItem.getTitleResId());
        mCurrentNavItem = navItem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }




    public void goToSearch(MenuItem item){

        //go to search page
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new Search();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }

    public void scanBarcode(MenuItem item){

        //open scanner
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();



    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result

            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();

            //todo: set scan content into setting, load new fragment which calls async task below. New
            //todo: fragment will have same ui as search. :-)
            Fragment Fragment_one;




            FragmentManager man= this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
            BarcodeFrag fragmentNew = new BarcodeFrag();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("scanContent", scanContent);
            fragmentNew.setArguments(bundle);


            tran.replace(R.id.main, fragmentNew);//tran.
            tran.addToBackStack(null);
            //tran.commit();
            tran.commitAllowingStateLoss();


        }

        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }



}
```

Which inflates a menu into the toolbar main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:onClick="goToSearch"
        android:title="Search"/>



    <item android:id="@+id/action_barcode"
        android:icon="@drawable/bar"
        android:title="barcode"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:onClick="scanBarcode"/>


</menu>
```

When a user clicks on the Search icon in my toolbar I load my search fragment and then I get this force close error:

```
03-03 20:32:53.852  11131-11131/com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial, PID: 11131
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView
            at com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.Search.onCreateOptionsMenu(Search.java:69)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1868)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1989)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:276)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:459)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:32:54.457  11131-11736/com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial I/Crashlytics﹕ Crashlytics report upload complete: 54F68AF00274-0001-2B7B-00FC717FCF0A.cls
03-03 20:32:55.807  11131-11131/com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11131 SIG: 9
```

The line 69 which is throwing the error in my Search.java file is:

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
```

My entire Search.java file is:

```
package com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 2/13/14.
 */

public class Search extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;
    SearchView searchView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;
    private Menu optionsMenu;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        //getActivity().setTitle("Search");


        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);


        return v;


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        this.optionsMenu = menu; // HERE

        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_searchHome);

        //searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }


    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {

        //toast query
        //make json variables to fill

        if (optionsMenu != null) {
            //(optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2)).collapseActionView();
        }


        // url to make request
        String url = "myURL";



        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String jsonUrl = url + query;


        //todo: get json
        ReadJSONResult task = new ReadJSONResult(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(jsonUrl);

        return false;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String b, String brewery){
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.postInvalidate();
        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();

        //adds beer data to shared prefs for beer tabs
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString("beerID",b);
        editor.putString("breweryID",brewery);
        editor.commit();
        Fragment_one = new BeerTabs();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }





}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import android.widget.SearchView;`

That's the wrong SearchView. You need to use the compat SearchView

`android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

Comment: This keeps it from crashing, but does not open up the search to begin typing to actually make a search.